# Multiple results - sql count

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 3 columns and I’ve tried count, sum, without any success. Any advice on what I should do here?

Table 1:

| Test_code | test_result | Patient_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112233 | POSITIVE | 1 |
| 445566 | 0.09 | 2 |
| 112233 | NEGATIVE | 3 |
| 445566 | 0.09 | 4 |
| 112233 | NEGATIVE | 5 |
| 445566 | 0.06 | 6 |

What I need for the Output:

| Test_code | test_result | total_result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112233 | POSITIVE | 1 |
| 112233 | NEGATIVE | 2 |
| 445566 | 0.09 | 2 |
| 445566 | 0.06 | 1 |

I have 3 columns and I’ve tried count, sum, without any success not sure if it’s because this column has numbers and text? Any advice on what I should do here?

Comment: Post what you have tried. It's a simple group by query.

Comment: In SQL/Snowflake you "cannot" have both numbers and text in one typed column. It is ether "strings" or variant, which is ~strings.. to have "both". And both can be used as `group by` clauses, so it mostly seems like you have not tried anything

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    Test_code, 
    test_result,
    COUNT(*) AS total_result
FROM 
    TestResults
GROUP BY 
    Test_code, test_result
ORDER BY 
    Test_code, test_result DESC;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/THwdGN5Q